# Can we declare global variable in QML file?

Tags: javascript, qml

I want to do something similer to following code:

```
//test.qml
import QtQuick 1.0
Item 
{
    var globalforJs =10;

    function increment() // JavaScript function
    {
        globalforJs++;
    }
    ....
QML Code
```

Can we have global variable in `QML file` and access it from the JavaScript function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try `property int globalForJs: 10;`

If you want a variable that can take any type:

`property var globalForJs: 10`

Prior to QML 2, use the `variant` keyword instead of `var`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can this `property variant globalForJs: 10` can be accessed from the java script function which is in QML file itself?

Comment: yes it can. All properties of a QML object can be accessed by any javascript function defined inside it.

Comment: But how to make this property `private`, so it is not seen by other QML stuff?

Comment: I don't think you can do that (javascript is not big on private member variables)

Answer (score 8):

Using `int` or `variant` properties do not create a javascript variable, but rather a semantically different generic QML property ([see here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-variant.html))

Before Qt 5, global javascript variables were recommended to be defined in a separately imported javascript file, however Qt 5 adds a `var` type [property support](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-var.html).

Answer (score -3):

the thing which you want to make global should be done like in this example

```
property variant name:"john"//i want this to be global
onCreationCompleted(){
Qt.name = name
}
```

whereever you want to use the name property use like `Qt.name` instead of just `name.this` also applicable for any ids of controls