# How to disable the scalability of QML objects

Tags: qt, qml

How to disable a the resizeability of QML objects? The height and width property of the object that I created are based on a scalable object, but i would not like for the object to be resized when the parent object is resized. How do I achieve this?

```
 Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        window.showMaximized()
    }

    Rectangle {
        width:parent.width/2
        height:parent.height/2
    }
}
```

With the code above the rectangle will be created with 1/2 the size of the parent, and I would it to stay that way. When I resize the window the rectangle resizes too, I would like for it to be fixed after it is created. How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I think I found a dupe: [How can I avoid creating a property binding on initialization in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551373/how-can-i-avoid-creating-a-property-binding-on-initialization-in-qml) :3

Answer (score 3):

Remove your property bindings.

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        window.showMaximized()
        rect.width = parent.width / 2;      // use these
        rect.height = parent.height / 2;
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        // width: parent.width/2    // no property bindings
        // height: parent.height/2
    }
}
```

By using property bindings on `rect.width` and `rect.height`, you're making them subject to **dynamic** change. You don't want that. Instead, you may call static assignments from Javascript.

If you place the JS code in `Component.onCompleted`, it will only run once (not updating every time the window resizes). These assignments won't create property bindings, fixing `rect.width` and `rect.height`.

Comment: The example i gave was for the sake of minimal code, so do i have to create an .onCompleted function every time i want and object size to be referred to ? Is this the cleanest approach ?

Comment: @Jack Well, you _could_ just simply do `rect.width = ...; rect.height = ...` so you don't necessarily need a `Component.onCompleted` every time you want to refer to the object (assuming you're referring to your rectangle from js).

Comment: Not sure entirely what you mean by cleanest. I guess it could be wrapped in a `set` function. You might need to give an example or two of how you're planning on using your object.

Comment: I have set my window to show.Maximized and i would like the size of the items inside it have their sized proportional to the maximized sized, and of course for its size to be static. There are a lot of nested objects under window so it would be kinda messy to keep writing Component.onCompleted.

Comment: The solution you gave works great it is just kinda tedious  for nested items :)

Comment: Then you should set custom properties `originalWidth`/`originalHeight` at creation, you only have to break the binding once and you can bind the width of every item to `originalWidth` (instead of `parent.width`) that will remain unchanged.