# I want to declare a global variable for flag in QML

Tags: variables, qml, global

**I want to declare a global variable for flag in QML.**
Like,

`var Flag = true;`

I need it so that I can use the **Flag**  at multiple places in QML file.
Is it possible without JavaScript or C++?

If yes, please reply and if not then please help me with coding for a JavaScript or C++ script.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe this can solve your problem, [Can we declare global variable in QML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515598/can-we-declare-global-variable-in-qml-file?rq=1)

Comment: This should also help, [declare global property in QML for other QML files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257946/declare-global-property-in-qml-for-other-qml-files)

Comment: @Matthew Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.!! Will try the program now and come back if there's an issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to declare a variable of bool form:

`property bool secondaryWindowisActive: false`

Here Bool is the type of variable named `secondaryWindowisActive` and its default value is `false` .